# Append to associate array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a source array

```
$A = array(
    0=> array(
        'title'=>'HTML5+CSS3',
        'teacher'=>'jonh',
        'id_post'=>1,/* link to  $post_formation */
        'formation'=>1,
        'date'=>'12/12/2112'
    )
);
```

and the an other array:

```
$post_formation = array(
            0=>array(1,2,3),
            1=>array(3,4,5)
        )
```

Look in `$A` to  manipulate a new restult (in this case `id_post=1` `1=>array(3,4,5)` so  will contain more `3 elements` )

```
$result = array(
    /* from $A */
    0=> array(
        'title'=>'HTML5+CSS3',
        'teacher'=>'jonh',
        'id_post'=>1,

        'formation'=>1,
        'date'=>'12/12/2112'
    ),

    /* Append here  more 03 elements `3,4,5` */
    1=> array(
        'title'=>'(A)HTML5+CSS3',
        'teacher'=>'jonh',
        'id_post'=>1,

        'formation'=>3,
        'date'=>'--/--/---'
    ),
    2=> array(
        'title'=>'(A)HTML5+CSS3',
        'teacher'=>'jonh',
        'id_post'=>1,

        'formation'=>4,
       'date'=>'--/--/----'
    ),
    3=> array(
        'title'=>'(A)HTML5+CSS3',
        'teacher'=>'jonh',
        'id_post'=>1,

        'formation'=>5,
        'date'=>'--/--/----'
    )
);
```

Anyone could tell me how todo this?

Comment: I don't quite see the logic. What have you tried, where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though a little weird......

```
$A=array(array("title"=>"HTML5+CSS3","teacher"=>"john","id_post"=>1,"formation"=>1,"date"=>"12/12/2012"));
$post_information=array(0=>array(1,2,3),1=>array(3,4,5));
print_r($A);
if(isset($post_information[$A[0]["id_post"]]))
{
    foreach($post_information[$A[0]["id_post"]] as $idx)
    {
        $cache=$A[0];
        $cache["title"]="(A)".$cache["title"];
        $cache["formation"]=$idx;
        $cache["date"]="--/--/----";
        $A[]=$cache;
    }
}
print_r($A);
```

Result:

The first `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => HTML+CSS3
            [teacher] => john
            [id_post] => 1
            [formation] => 1
            [date] => 12/12/2012
        )

)
```

The second `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => HTML+CSS3
            [teacher] => john
            [id_post] => 1
            [formation] => 1
            [date] => 12/12/2012
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => (A)HTML+CSS3
            [teacher] => john
            [id_post] => 1
            [formation] => 3
            [date] => --/--/----
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => (A)HTML+CSS3
            [teacher] => john
            [id_post] => 1
            [formation] => 4
            [date] => --/--/----
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => (A)HTML+CSS3
            [teacher] => john
            [id_post] => 1
            [formation] => 5
            [date] => --/--/----
        )

)
```

You can of course wrap the logic in a function instead of plainly modify the source `$A`.

Comment: If array `A` more elements Can it apply?

Comment: @BandOfBrothers That depends on what the source will look like in "more elements" and what do you expect the result would be. Update your question with a "more elements" example (and expected result) and I'll see if I can make it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way and probably much simpler

```
  $ArrayPayChannel=array();

 function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
  $array[$key] = $value;
 return $array;
 }

 $ArrayPayChannel = array_push_assoc($ArrayPayChannel, 'Key', 'Value');
```

and if you have more depth in the array instead of value you van put another array_push_assoc($ArrayPayChannel, 'Key', 'Value'); and you have more depth as you want